# Compare dateTime Now to date in format ("2019-01-01 00:00:00.000")

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date coming from a database in the form of 2019-06-20 00:00:00.000
that i need to compare to the time of now.. (+ 7 days reset to midnight)
Specifically like:

```
if ($databasedatetime > $now){
}
else {}
```

so far i have done this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$now->getTimestamp();
$now->modify('midnight');
$now->modify('+7 day');
```

But when it tries to compare I always get false regardless if it's true or not. So they are not comparing correctly.

my now function clearly needs modifying to set it to `"2019-01-01 00:00:00.000"` format.
as at the moment it prints out like `2019-01-15 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London` instead

Any help converting my $now variable into "2019-01-01 00:00:00.000" would be much appreciated

Comment: Start with `var_dump($databasedatetime);`

Comment: Is `$databasedatetime` a string or a DateTime object?

Comment: From the var_dump.. it looks like its a string: string(23) "2020-01-11 00:00:00.000"

Comment: So convert it to DateTime object and compare these objects.

Comment: Used: $Ddate=date_create($databasedatetime);
  date_format($Ddate,"Y/m/d H:i:s.v"); & now it compares perfectly! thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Compare timestamp you can do this:

  `if (new DateTime($databasedatetime) > $now){
  }
  else {}`
  convert `$databasedatetime` to a DateTime instance for comparison.
- If you want to convert `$now` to format like "2019-01-01 00:00:00.000" you can try `$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.v')`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `DateTime` object from the string, which comes from the database before the comparison.

```
$time = strtotime($databasedatetime);
$databasetimeFormatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
if ($databasetimeFormatted > $now) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a method createFromFormat for \DateTime: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
<?php
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", "2019-06-20 00:00:00.000");
$now = new \DateTime();
var_dump($date,$now);
var_dump($date > $now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `var_dump($databasedatetime);` Turns out `$now` was correctly in DateTime but
`$databasedatetime` was just a string. Hence could not compare.

So convert $databasedatetime to string.

I used

```
$Ddate=date_create($databasetimedate);
date_format($Ddate,"Y/m/d H:i:s.v");
```

now i can compare like

```
if ($Ddate > $now){...
```